# Values of pie chart overlaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, donut-chart

I want to see the values clearly, how can I fix that? How can I locate my values manually?
(values of gray and black colors (0.4) overlaps)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.DataFrame({'Fiziki Durum':[173,76,1,1]},index=['Bina İçerisinde','Müstakil','Gezici','Prefabrik'])

labels='Bina İçerisinde','Müstakil','Gezici','Prefabrik'
colors=('#3a88e2','#5c9e1e','#708090','#0e1111')

fig1, ax=plt.subplots()

sizes=[173,76,1,1]
explode = (0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05)

patches, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90,explode=explode,  autopct='%1.1f%%' )

plt.legend(patches, labels, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.08), ncol=4, frameon=False)

#draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

ax.axis('equal')  
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: my plot]

Comment: In this case, rearrange the order of the data as follows: largest, smallest, second largest, second smallest, and so on to avoid overlap.

Comment: Wow quick solution! Thanks, and how can I locate other values to the centers? @r-beginners

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but you can get it by looping through the list in descending and ascending sort order twice with the zip function.

Comment: Try this: `sizes=[173,76,1,1]
new_sizes = []
for l,s in zip(sizes, sizes[::-1]):
    new_sizes.append(l)
    new_sizes.append(s)
new_sizes[:4]`

Comment: Thanks mate! But I wrote pctdistance=0.85 into ax.pie() and it worked on writing the values on the centres